# How to find the latest commits in one git repository?

Tags: git, github

I have one git repository, there are many branches many commits, I want to find the latest 10 commits, how to do this , thanks!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you want commits for all branches you need the --all argument, limit git log to ten with -10 and use --date-order to tell git log to sort the commits with respect to date.

```
git log -10 --all --date-order
```

Answer (score 7):

For last 10 commits in all branches, you can do:

```
git log --graph --all --format=format:'%h - (%ai) %s — %cn %d' \ 
  --abbrev-commit --date=relative -10
```

- %h is the commit hash
- %ai is author date (use %ci for committer date)
- %s is the commit subject
- %cn is the committer name
- -10 means last 10 commits

See here for more info if you need to customize further:
http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-log

Answer (score 4):

To find specific number of commits you can use the `-n` option :

```
git log -5  # or git log -n 5 # fetches the last 5 commits
```

As, @honk pointed out,  `-n 5` and `-5` are equivalent.

To find commits on other branch, without checking out the other branch :

```
git log branch_name
```

So, if you are at develop branch and wish to get last 10 commits of master(oneline), you could do:

```
git log --oneline master  -10
```

To view commits of all branches there's a `--all` argument.

```
git log --all
```

Comment: You could have written that `-n 5` and `-5` are equivalent. And to see all branches of course use `-all` (talking about how hard the git CLI is).

Comment: @honk - yea. And I think you meant `--all`. I'll update the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `git log --graph` & you will get the commits in the order latest to old along with

```
•the checksum of the commit 
•the author name and email 
•the date the author committed it 
•the full commit message
```

**EDIT:**

or you can use:

`git log --pretty=oneline --graph`

which gives all the commits & branch topology

Comment: I want to get latest commits in all branches