# Git equivalent of Mercurial tip tag

Tags: git, mercurial, bitbucket

Is there any way how to refer to latest git commit  in a repository (regardles of a branch)?

We are moving from mercurial to git. One of our CI integration tests verifies latest commit to a specific repo. It uses the tip tag to retrieve it (it downloads a .zip from Bitbucket cloud using the 'tip.zip' reference). Now I'm wondering if this is achievable in git without need to sync the repo (there are internal reasons why the test uses zip download instead of checkout/sync).

Comment: Maybe it's my ignorance of mercurial, but what value does knowing the latest commit to the entire repo provide? At least in Git, it would seem like a rather arbitrary thing to track.

Comment: @chepner That's irrespective of concrete VCS. In our case our build has a step evaluating cross-compatibility of main FW and plugin module. We are evaluating LKG (named branch), latest (master), and latest in-progress (this was the tip) version of the plugin. This test is a part of FW (not to run it for each plugin repo commit, as most expensive part is the FW build).

Comment: @chepner - just use-case from https://serverfault.com/questions/202061/whats-the-difference-between-mercurials-tip-tag-and-the-default-branch#comment804462_202099. Handy short memorable reference to "last **modified** changeset in repo" (torek is totally wrong with "highest local number" statement)

Comment: @LazyBadger: technically, you cannot modify a changeset. What you can do is replace it with another changeset, but the new one will have a different hash ID. https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/FAQ/TechnicalDetails: "The changeset hash (the changeset ID) is again a hash of the changeset contents and its parents ..." Replace some changeset and you get a new, different changeset - which gets the numerically highest local revision number.

Comment: @torek - **If** I'm interested in "last-modified", only *this* is important for me, nor rev-id|hash. Please, re-read words highlighted by me, in order to see difference between "technical" and "real-life" reqs, as outlined it referenced by me good use-case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mercurial's *tip* is simply the last modified head in the repository.  This works because Mercurial numbers each commit as it goes *into* the repository.  This number is not useful in any *clone* of the repository as the same commit(s) might be in the clone but might have arrived in a different order, or arrived after some other commit that is in that other repository (that is not in this one) got in.<sup>1</sup>

Taking the most recently incorporated, and therefore numerically last, commit in a Mercurial repository is not a good way to work, because the commit that just went in a moment ago might be on some sort of test or backup branch that has nothing to do with the real work people are doing.  You should instead be taking a *specific* latest commit—the latest proposed-for-inclusion-in-release, or latest-for-development, or whatever.<sup>2</sup>  (You can get this easily in both Mercurial and Git.)

In any case, Git simply has no notion of "latest in repository".  Each *branch name* in Git defines the latest commit in that *branch*, so "tip of `develop`" or "tip of `master`" or whatever is simply "the commit identified by that name".  Whether and how you can download a zip file of those commits is up to your hosting provider, but `git archive` makes this easy, so chances are very good that you can easily do the *right* thing.  Don't even try to do the *wrong* thing, which Git doesn't provide.

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that the *name* `tip` in any other clone will name *its* highest-numbered revision.  If the same changesets both just went in to both repositories, they may have different local numbers, but the last one will have the highest local number.  In this particular case, then, `tip` in each repository would name the same changeset.

See also [the Mercurial FAQ, under the definitions of "head" and "tip"](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/FAQ#FAQ.2FTerminology.What_are_branches.2C_merges.2C_heads.2C_and_the_tip.3F).  Note how each changeset has two numbers: a local, simple incrementing count, and a hash ID: `0:838e`, `1:3fe4`, `2:4563`, and so on.  Git has the hash ID, but not the locally-useful, incrementing and easy-to-use number.  Git thus forces you to use a raw hash ID, or a branch name.

(I'm not sure how `tip` plays with the Hg Evolve extension.  I imagine it still just refers to the highest local revision number, since you would outdate an old head by inserting a new head.  This would maintain the property that the Mercurial tip is always a head, although not all Mercurial heads are the tip—only one head can be the tip.)

<sup>2</sup>You also run the risk of someone else delivering new commits to the repository while you're not looking, so that either `tip` *or* a branch name refers to an even-newer commit than the one you intended.  Ideally, you want a unique *unchanging* identifier for a commit.  That would be its hash ID.  You can use a hash ID in both VCSes, but hash IDs are, at the least, annoying.  This risk may be outweighed by the convenience of names.

Comment: @LazyBadger: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/FAQ#FAQ.2FTerminology.What_are_branches.2C_merges.2C_heads.2C_and_the_tip.3F "The tip is the changeset added to the repository most recently. If you have just made a commit, that commit will be the tip. Alternately, if you have just pulled from another repository, the tip of that repository becomes the new tip. Use hg tip to show the tip of the repository." This is also what I said: it's the numerically highest `-r` revision.

Comment: @LazyBadger: try pulling in a revision made a few seconds ago, and then pulling in a revision made a day ago in a separate clone. Which one is the tip? Which changeset is the "most recent" by date-stamp? Which one has the highest local number? If you insist on the phrase "added most recently", that's OK, but that means *the same thing* as "has the highest local revision number". Note that Mercurial is nicer here than Git because Git's `--date-order` looks at the embedded committer date, which can be anything; you can't actually see how things were added to the repository.

Comment: No, not "the same", because I can ''commit --amend" to old head. and it will be tip with old revid ("local number")

Comment: `hg commit --amend` changes *my* commit to be the new highest number:
`hg checkout side` `1 files updated, 0 files merged, 1 files removed, 0 files unresolved` ... `@  2:a9c4acc2ef8d:draft  side ...` ... `hg commit --amend` `saved backup bundle to .../.hg/strip-backup/a9c4acc2ef8d-edcc1c56-amend.hg` `hg tip` `changeset:   3:619209a9eb6b` This is now the highest rev, whereas the commit I amended was `-r 2` before. See: highest number.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's multiple ways to get the most-recent commit.

The brute-force method is simply `:/`, that looks at all refs and picks the most recent one whose commit message matches the regex after the `/`, it's empty here, a trivial match.  Try `git show :/` for instance.

If you've got a set of candidates you're interested in, the default sequence for rev-list-based commands is commit-date order, so e.g.

```
git rev-list -1 --no-walk master maint make
```

will show you just the most recent commit of the three named commits.

But why do you care about dates anyway?  Don't you want to ci anything you haven't yet ci'd?  Ancestry structure matters.  Git knows that simultaneity is an issue in dvcs's just as it is in physics, if you want to know which happened first you might have to care who's asking, and why.  j

> it downloads a .zip from Bitbucket cloud using the 'tip.zip' reference). Now I'm wondering if this is achievable in git without need to sync the repo (there are internal reasons why the test uses zip download instead of checkout/sync

but this makes me think you're trying to force Git into Mercurial's straitjacket.  `git fetch` can be asked/configured to fetch only and exactly what you want, `git fetch origin +master:refs/remotes/origin/master` will fetch only the updates to the master tip, and it'll fetch it deltified.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you (possibly) can. According to this relatively old [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9679564/960558), you can use (TBT!, I don't have Git and can't test result):

`git log -1 --all --date-order`

(where `-1` is number of changesets, `--all` for "from all branches" and `--date-order` sort the commits with respect to date)